# Calculating the intersection between two planes

Tags: geometry

EDIT: Let me give you the full problem at hand.

We have an Orthonormal CS in E3*. According to that, we must find an analytical representation of a central projection c  of E3* over the plane alpha: $$2x-y+z=0$$ with an infinite center Ug, where the line g is the intersection of the two planes described below.

I have a part of a problem where I must calculate the intersection of two planes
$$3x+y-z+4t=0 \\
y+2t=0$$

From the second one I can derive $$y=-2t$$ and then I substitute that in the first to get $$3x-z+2t=0$$
Now, from my understanding, from that equation, I must get the coordinates of the line using only this. However, I have one equation and two variables (given that `t` is some constant). Do I have to set one of the variables, say $$z=p$$, or is there any other procedure I must follow?

As a bonus, this line is an infinite (?) center $$Ug$$ of a third plane. How do I find the coordinates of the `Ug`?

Comment: You're already done. The intersection is given by $3x - z + 2t = 0$. These two planes intersect to make that line.

Comment: But aren't I supposed to be able to write the coordinates of the line like {x1, y1, z1, t} ??

Comment: When you say "I must **calculate** the intersection of 2 planes", do you know exactly what you are looking for ? Are you looking for a parametric representation $x=a+bt, y=c+dt$ (i.e; a "point-vector" representation) ?

Comment: I don't really understand my problem entirely, so I'm not sure. Here is the whole thing:   Given an OCS in E3* find an analytical representation of a central projection of c of E3* over the plane `alpha` with an infinite center `Ug` where Ug is the intersection of the two planes described above. So I'm not really sure what's going to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two planes give a line. What you must first do is solve the system finding a point in the intersection. The the vector parametrization for the line is given by $\gamma(t) = \vec{p} + t(\vec{n_1} \times \vec{n_2})$ where $\vec{n_i}$ represents the normal vector for the plane $P_i$. You may also find two points in the intersection and use as your direction vector $\vec{v} = p_2 - p_1$, but you'll see that this vector is parallel to the cross product of the normal vectors.